# String concatination too long error oracle

Tags: database, oracle

While am fetching records from the database am getting the `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`.

Am having more rows in the table to.

Please find my query below.

```
SELECT MAX(LTRIM(sys_connect_by_path(TO_CHAR(rn) 
  ||'.' 
  ||MESSAGE,'~'),'~')) MESSAGE 
FROM 
  (SELECT tif, 
    MESSAGE, 
    ROWNUM rn 
  FROM BULL_MESS msg, 
    BULL_MAPPING MAP 
  WHERE map.tif        = ? 
  AND msg.message_id   = MAP.message_id 
  AND msg.enabled_flag = 'Y' 
  ) 
  START WITH rn       = 1 
  CONNECT BY PRIOR rn = rn-1 
MINUS 
SELECT NULL FROM dual
```

Comment: You may use recursive subquery to build the same string with `clob`, which has no such limit

Answer (score 0):

The `sys_connect_by_path` function returns a `varchar2`. `varchar2s` have a length limit of 4000 bytes in SQL. You must be exceeding that length.

Also, are you sure `max` is what you want in your query?